# How should I get stored procedure result set in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that named globalsearch. the stored procedure return some results. the problem is how should I get results that is returned stored procedure in sql server 2005.thanks!

Comment: to get more help you need to provide more information. in what language and/or context are you trying to receive the stored procedure result set?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to get the result of a procedure from another procedure, the only way is to capture it into a table insert. See this article on MSDN covering the subject in detail: [Getting Creative with EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175921(SQL.80).aspx).